# Spark Streaming Accumulated Word Count

Tags: scala, distributed, apache-spark, spark-streaming

This is a spark streaming program written in scala. It counts the number of words from a socket in every 1 second. The result would be the word count, for example, the word count from time 0 to 1, and the word count then from time 1 to 2. But I wonder if there is some way we could alter this program so that we could get accumulated word count? That is, the word count from time 0 up till now.

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("NetworkWordCount")
val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))

// Create a socket stream on target ip:port and count the
// words in input stream of \n delimited text (eg. generated by 'nc')
// Note that no duplication in storage level only for running locally.
// Replication necessary in distributed scenario for fault tolerance.
val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(args(0), args(1).toInt, StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK_SER)
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
val wordCounts = words.map(x => (x, 1)).reduceByKey(_ + _)
wordCounts.print()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use a [`StateDStream`](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/streaming/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/streaming/dstream/StateDStream.scala) for this. There is an [example of stateful word count from sparks examples](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/streaming/StatefulNetworkWordCount.scala).

```
object StatefulNetworkWordCount {
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    if (args.length < 2) {
      System.err.println("Usage: StatefulNetworkWordCount <hostname> <port>")
      System.exit(1)
    }

    StreamingExamples.setStreamingLogLevels()

    val updateFunc = (values: Seq[Int], state: Option[Int]) => {
      val currentCount = values.foldLeft(0)(_ + _)

      val previousCount = state.getOrElse(0)

      Some(currentCount + previousCount)
    }

    val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("StatefulNetworkWordCount")
    // Create the context with a 1 second batch size
    val ssc = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Seconds(1))
    ssc.checkpoint(".")

    // Create a NetworkInputDStream on target ip:port and count the
    // words in input stream of \n delimited test (eg. generated by 'nc')
    val lines = ssc.socketTextStream(args(0), args(1).toInt)
    val words = lines.flatMap(_.split(" "))
    val wordDstream = words.map(x => (x, 1))

    // Update the cumulative count using updateStateByKey
    // This will give a Dstream made of state (which is the cumulative count of the words)
    val stateDstream = wordDstream.updateStateByKey[Int](updateFunc)
    stateDstream.print()
    ssc.start()
    ssc.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

The way it works is you get an `Seq[T]` for each batch, then you update an `Option[T]` which acts like an accumulator. The reason it is an `Option` is because on the first batch it will be `None` and stay that way unless it's updated. In this example the count is an int, if you are dealing with a lot of data you may want to even have a `Long` or `BigInt`

Answer (score -1):

I have a very simple answer and its just few lines of code. you can find this is most of the spark books. remember that I have used localhost and port 9999.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.streaming import StreamingContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonStreamingNetworkWordCount")
ssc = StreamingContext(sc, 1)
lines = ssc.socketTextStream("localhost", 9999)
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))\
                     .map(lambda word: (word, 1))\
                     .reduceByKey(lambda a, b: a+b)
counts.pprint()
ssc.start()
ssc.awaitTermination()
```

and to stop you can use a simple

`ssc.stop()`

This is a very basic code but this code is helpful in a basic understanding of spark streaming, Dstream to be more specific.

to give input to the localhost in your terminal (Mac terminal) type

`nc -l 9999`

so it would listen to everything you type after that and the words would be counted

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Practically, it's the solution in question implemented in PySpark.