# Invoking updateStateByKey twice on the same RDD

Tags: scala, cassandra, apache-spark, apache-kafka

Can I invoke UpdateStateByKey twice on the same RDD. My requirement is as follows.

1. Get the event stream from Kafka
2. UpdateStateByKey to aggregate and filter set of events based on timestamp
3. Do some processing and save to Cassandra DB
4. UpdateStateByKey to remove the key based on an eventType

I tried doing it assigning results from step 2 to a VAR and reassigning it to the updated value in step 4. But seems it does not work that way. I am new to spark and not sure how this kind of behaviour is possible.

Appreciate any help.

Comment: this answer should explain how update state by key works, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24771823/spark-streaming-accumulated-word-count/24771886#24771886, and yes you should be able to call updateStateByKey more than once on the same RDD, you may want to cache if you do that, to receive more help you should post an attempt of what you have done

Comment: you mean, I should use broadcast variable, or RDD persistence like, cache(), persist(), not sure which one would exactly help in the above case

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by actually doing the cleanup I wanted to do in a second call to updateStateByKey() at the beginning of my state update method. A small example:

```
private static Optional<State> updateState(
        final List<Events> allEvents,
        final Optional<State> state) {
    State state = state.or(State::new);
    state.clearAccumulatedValues();

    // Do some work...
    state.addValue("Purple Elephants!");

    return Optional.fromNullable(state.isEmpty() ? null : state);
}
```